# boost::get vs boost::apply_visitor when fetching values from a variant

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant

We are using collections of boost::variant extensively in our production code.
The way we extract the values from this collection is

```
for (auto & var : vars)
{
    switch (var.which())
    {
        case 1 :
        AVal = boost::get<A>(var);
        break;
        case 2 :
        BVal = boost::get<B> (var);
        ...
     } 
}
```

Reading more about variants I can see that a different alternative would be

```
for (auto & var : vars)
{
    switch (var.which())
    {
        case 1 :
        AVal = boost::apply_visitor(AVisitor, var);
        break;
        case 2 :
        BVal = boost::apply_visitor(BVisitor, var);
        ...
    } 
}
```

Ignoring the fact that apply_visitor provides compile time type safe value visitation and is more powerful, should I expect any difference in terms of run time performance for either of the above approaches?

Comment: Both of those read as code smell to me.  Is there a reason you aren't doing the work within the visitor?

Comment: What do you mean when you say "not doing the work within the visitor"? This is just a dummy example, In the real case there would be proper implementations for A/BVisitor classes if that is what you mean...

Comment: don't write pseudo code for something you don't understand.  I can see no good reason to do a switch before visiting; **visiting is a switch operation**.  By the time I translate your pseudo code to code that isn't nonsense, it will have very little in common with what you are doing in your real code, barring extreme luck. [Mcve] please.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::variant` is just a block of memory that is aligned to biggest data type you provide, and an integer specifying which of these types is currently use. And a lot of compile-time macros allowing for visitation logic.

Discarding one or two run-time checks making sure right type is getting grabbed, there should be no other cost for accessing that memory location, reinterpreted as the desired type.

Comment: But if I have to compare the above two methods. Which is more preferable, performance wise?

Comment: `boost::get` would be ever so slightly better. That is the case since for `boost::apply_visitor` it's required to instantiate the visitor and then apply it for the the member, which `boost::get` does not have to do. However, I would go with `boost::apply_visitor` every time. One more function call is a more than fair price to pay for type safety and clean code.

Comment: @aybassiouny What I have observed(via debugging), is that boost::get() and my definition of apply_visitor, both, ultimately execute the same meta-programmed switch. The only difference being that boost::get() uses and hence does instantiates the generic visitor while in the latter case, its the explicitly defined visitor that gets called. Also,  I had a performance comparison among the two and apply_visitor seemed to be faster.